# CSS nth-of-type is not working

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Using the `nth-of-type` selector in CSS doesn't work for me. It applies the style of the first child to the rest of its siblings. So what happens is all the `home-navigation-item` divs are all colored aqua.

```css
   .home-navigation-item:nth-of-type(1) {
     background-color: aqua;
   }
   .home-navigation-item:nth-of-type(2) {
     background-color: red;
   }
```

```html
<div class="home-navigation">
  <a href="news.html">
    <div class="home-navigation-item">NEWS</div>
  </a>
  <a href="announcements.html">
    <div class="home-navigation-item">ANNOUNCEMENTS</div>
  </a>
  <a href="events.html">
    <div class="home-navigation-item">SCHEDULE OF EVENTS</div>
  </a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not working because it has multiple parents. `nth-of-type` works on direct siblings, not their parent and then on the siblings, or when all of the elements are the same with no distinguishable parent (they are all `<a>` tags). So it's better to target the siblings' parent, then the element just above, then the element, itself. [**Read This**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp)

```css
.home-navigation a:nth-of-type(1) .home-navigation-item{
   background-color: aqua;
}

.home-navigation a:nth-of-type(2) .home-navigation-item{
   background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="home-navigation">
        <a href="news.html"><div class="home-navigation-item"> NEWS </div></a>
        <a href="announcements.html"><div class="home-navigation-item"> ANNOUNCEMENTS </div></a>
        <a href="events.html"><div class="home-navigation-item"> SCHEDULE OF EVENTS</div></a>
</div>
```

We get the parent they all have in common, then use `nth-of-type` on the `<a>` elements because they have these in common, not the `home-navigation-item` divs.

Comment: Nice, Works good.  I'd probably suggest OP not place divs inside anchors unless its unavoidable somewhy. I'd prefer:  `<div><a href = #>anchor text</a></div>` then: `a {display: inline-block; width: 100%;}` Makes selecting them simpler, too.

Comment: Thanks! @2-centstim, I wanted to make the whole div selectable but your suggestion is way better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ganesh had a good explanation for why you can't use `nth-of-type` on the divs - the anchor tags above them need that, instead, if you went that way:

```
.home-navigation a:nth-of-type(1) .home-navigation-item{
   background-color: aqua;
}

.home-navigation a:nth-of-type(2) .home-navigation-item{
   background-color:red;
}
```

But another way to deal with it, instead, is to just apply some IDs on the `<div>` tags and you can just do CSS on them directly, instead:

```css
div#news {
   background-color: aqua;
}

div#announcements {
   background-color:red;
}

div#events {
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="home-navigation">
        <a href="news.html"><div id="news" class="home-navigation-item"> NEWS </div></a>
        <a href="announcements.html"><div id="announcements" class="home-navigation-item"> ANNOUNCEMENTS </div></a>
        <a href="events.html"><div id="events" class="home-navigation-item"> SCHEDULE OF EVENTS</div></a>
</div>
```

You could do the same thing with a class instead of an ID, just you would use a `.` instead of the `#` if you do that, and you would have to use different class names if you want them to be different colors. The point to having the same class name is that you want everything to look alike.